# jquery click not getting triggered on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen a lot of posts on this issue but none of the solutions worked. The following..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.login_linkedinbutton").click(function(){
    $("#signup-form").submit();
    return false;
  });
});

</script>
```

is what I have in the body tag of a page. Also in the body is the form, the html of which in IE shows up like this..

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/auth/linkedin" class="well form-inline" id="signup-form" method="post">
  <a class="login_linkedinbutton" href="#">Login using Linkedin</a>
</form>
```

in IE8, when the link within the form is clicked, the jquery is not getting triggered. It's working in Chrome and Firefox. I've tried:

1) Using the live event to bind the click action
2) Moved the jquery out of the page and into rails assets

Any ideas what else to try?

Comment: Although awful, have you tried `href="javascript:$('#signup-form').submit(); return false;"`?

Comment: how about just changing the anchor to a submit button ?

Comment: Have you tried inserting `javascript:void(0);"' in your href, instead of using the "#"?

Comment: If you're not going to change the anchor, try `document.getElementById("signup-form").submit();` and see if that submits the form ?

Comment: It works for me in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/XPUFM/ Well, in IE9 atleast. can't test Ie8 in fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the help folks. Yes, true I would rather use a button too but I'm collaborating with web designers who've given me styled links rather than buttons. So for now i need the links to work.

Comment: I got to the bottom of this. Somewhere else in my jquery code (unrelated to this code) there was something IE didn't link and interpreted it as a syntax error which I guess was making all jquery after it to not work. I installed IE developer tools and noticed this issue when reloaded the page. After fixing the "syntax" error, this was fixed also. I've however changed the # to void :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `<input type="submit" value="Login using Linkedin">`
Why create problems by using a non-standard element and then trying to recover from it?

If you want it to LOOK like a link, just style the button. But why do it? It's poor user experience to suggest the user to go to another page while they're submitting a form. Most users avoid clicking links when they have a form filled because they're afraid of loosing what they just typed.

If you insist using the link, you could try this:

```
var onLinkedInLogin = function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the link processing
    $("#signup-form").submit();
    // add return false; if you want to stop event propagation also
    // equivalent to calling both, e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation().
};

$(document).on('click', 'a.login_linkedinbutton', onLinkedInLogin);
```

The reason I'm suggesting using `.on()` instead on `.click()` is that I guess that on IE, the `a.login_linkedinbutton` is not present in the DOM when you call the `.click()`.

Comment: I agree with @BLSully . . . you are making the assumption that he can change it.  There are many reasons why he might not be able to (standards or requirement restrictions for a project, for example). Better to ask if he can make the change than assume it.

Comment: @BLSully: On the contrary:  Sometimes the most correct answer is "don't do that".  :P

Comment: @absolutskyy, you're welcome. Let's keep in  mind, no communication here is personal. A lot of people look here for a reference to their problems. The common mindset is to fix the error, not the design. Which is why I felt it suitable to have this as an answer. I trust in absolutskyy's abilities to estimate the suitability of the solution in his context, but leaving this answer out, might leave some less experienced programmers in the mindset that's it's OK to omit submit button and then hack a link to do it's job.

Comment: @Jani Hyytiäinen good job man! You are teaching others how to catch good fish instead of spoon-feeding them